# Regex for single letter with dot after and stuff around? php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following being stored in a variable

```
>a.<

>b.<

>c.<
```

but there's a bunch of other stuff around it, what regex would I use to match

```
>(.*).<
```

where (.*) is any single letter?

Comment: Just so you know, `.` matches any character and `*` in this context means "the previous character 0 or more times"

Comment: Ah ok I never really understood what exactly that meant thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this regular expression: `\>([a-zA-Z])\.\<`

The dot is a control character that must be escaped.  The `[]` specifies a range for a single character.

EDIT:

These characters needs to be escaped: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -` according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php.  I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this pattern:

```
>[^\.]+\.<
```

Independent of any specific character (other than last dot), just in the same way as yours.